# Total orthonormal set which is not a basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hamel-basis

Does there exist a total orthonormal set in a Hilbert space which is not a basis?
In a separable Hilbert space every total orthonormal set is a basis. What if the Hilbert space is not separable?

Comment: No, there is no such orthonormal set, countable or uncountable.

Comment: If total means maximal orthonormal set, then it is a basis.

Comment: so does it mean that every total orthonormal set is a basis irrespective of whether the space is separable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Any orthonormal set of vectors is independent.  If "total" means that there is no other vector normal to all of the given vectors then they also span the space so are a basis.

Comment: u mean "complete" orthonormal set?...total set is closure of span equals the space